# Plots for two variables within a group about each other with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to use ggplot2 to plot two variables for multiple (in the example below: 4) individuals. Now I want that for every individual, the graphs for the two variables are about each other.

Example data:

```
da = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4), day = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4), var1= c(3,4,2,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,3,2,1,2,3), var2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2))
```

I can do the plots for the two variables separately:

```
da %>% ggplot(aes(x= day, y = var1)) + geom_line()+ facet_wrap(~id, nrow = 2) 
da %>% ggplot(aes(x= day, y = var2)) + geom_line()+ facet_wrap(~id, nrow = 2)
```

I get two separate plots:

[image: Separate Plot 1][image: Separate Plot 2]

But what I want is this (...I moved the plots with Paint to show you what I need):

[image: Target Plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pivoting to longer:

```
library(tidyverse)

da %>%
  pivot_longer(var1:var2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = value)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(name ~ id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an approach using `patchwork` where you can arrange your plots as you desire. The solution of @arg0naut91 is a great way to tackle the issue but if you want to place plots without faceting you can use next code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
#Data
da = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                day = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                var1= c(3,4,2,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,3,2,1,2,3),
                var2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2))
#Plots
G1 <- da %>% ggplot(aes(x= day, y = var1)) + geom_line()+ facet_wrap(~id, nrow = 1) 
G2 <- da %>% ggplot(aes(x= day, y = var2)) + geom_line()+ facet_wrap(~id, nrow = 1) 
#Bind plots
G1/G2
wrap_plots(G1,G2,ncol = 1)
```

Output:

[image]